# How do I create multi form template with the control assigned to the form and display when user select

Tags: asp.net

I am a newbie to asp.net and I would like to ask if anyone could advise me on my query below.

I wanted to create a site that allows user to build their own templates and define their own controls (such as textbook, listbox bind to a dataset, combo box and radio button)

Once these templates are created they will set to publish and make it into a normalised form. Other users will go to this publish site to click on the template and fill the data for processing. And going forward, the author of the templates could amend the template and make changes.

Could anyone advise how to go about? It would be nice if there is any example that I could read and try

Thank you and appreciate your great help

Comment: Is it a problem of Asp.net core or .Net Framework? Which one?

Comment: Asp.net framework